# Laravel Class 'Memcached' not found Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector.php line 44

Tags: php, caching, laravel, memcached, composer-php

I've just clone my git repo from BitBucket on my computer to refresh my sites directory, and attempted a composer install/update to bring myself back up to scratch.

I'm now faced with:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Memcached' not found","file":"\/Users\/Ed\/Sites\/metinet_api\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cache\/MemcachedConnector.php","line":44}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

This was working before the fresh clone, and caching with tags (Memcached) is hard coded into my application, so it would not be ideal to use a different driver.

I'm using an OS X machine.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Many thanks, Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Memcached` is not a Laravel class — it's a PHP class [provided by a PHP extension](https://www.php.net/Memcached).  Your OS X machine doesn't have the PHP `Memcached` extension installed.  Get that installed (with a `memcached` server backing it) and you'll be good to go.

If you're not up for [homebrewing](http://brew.sh/) this yourself, then [this package](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) has always been my defacto go to on OS X to get most of the goodies a modern PHP developer will need. You could also consider abandoning running your stack locally and give in to [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) (running *nix VMs locally will your installed software)

Comment: Hey Alan.  I'm using Laravel Homestead with Vagrant.  I've been developing this application for about 6 months with no issues.  Memcached is installed, as I can see it in my phpinfo().  This is why I'm a bit confused? Ed

Comment: Alan, tried the package but kept running into access denied issues.  So uninstalled homebrew, and reinstalled.  Then reinstalled memcached.  Still not working..?

Comment: If PHP can't find Memcached then Memcached isn't installed, or isn't enabled via php.ini, or the version of PHP serving pages isn't the version of PHP you installed.

Comment: I've got the brew process to work. Much easier than anything I've used before. The main issue was that I had moved the default path for php.ini to a third party php.ini, so any changes I made were not being made on the php.ini I was using. Now I've changed that, installing via brew is a breeze. Thanks Alan!

Answer (score 0):

If you've just cloned your repo you probably need to run composer update to get all of your dependencies? I'm guessing your vendor/ folder is empty right now, its certainly missing the memcached class

Cheers
Ash Finlayson

Comment: Hi Ash, I've done the composer install/update.  My vendor folder is full, but I can't run phpunit or run migrations due to the memcached error shown above.  The last message shown after performing the composer install/update is the error shown above. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed that, maybe a stupid question but have you tried restarting memcache?

Comment: Ash, I've now uninstalled homebrew as above, reinstalled memcached.  Done a restart.  Still not working...?